# ERROR: Directory is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, pip

I've got the following error:

```
ERROR: Directory is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml'
```

Background is that I'm following a guide online to expose an ML model via API Gateway on AWS that can be found here:
[Hosting your ML model on AWS Lambdas + API Gateway](https://towardsdatascience.com/hosting-your-ml-model-on-aws-lambdas-api-gateway-part-1-9052e6b63b25)

I'm trying to pull some python packages into a local folder using the following command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps --target python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

I have also tried this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

and all I get is the above error.
Google is pretty bare when it comes to help with this issue, any ideas?

thanks,

Comment: `--target` ? Double minuses.

Comment: @phd - was my typo in the original post, sorry. I had already tried --target and -t

Comment: Can you try to specify package inside `pip install` command instead of using `-r requirements.txt` ? Maybe that solves the problem...

Comment: *Probably* your `requirements.txt` contains something like `-e .` which attempts to install the current directory as a package, too, which of course does not work if it isn't an installable package (i.e. it doesn't have either of those two files).

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

You can create a new folder e.g. `lib`, and run this command:

```
pip3 install <your_python_module_name> -t lib/
```

Comment: He could do `-t .` to install in the same directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following commands in the following order worked for me:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your package, requirment.txt & setup.py in same folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Please try this:

```
   ADD requirements.txt ./
   pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

> syntax: ADD source destination

'ADD requirements.txt ./' adds requirements.txt (assumed to be at the cwd) to the docker image's './' folder.

Thus creating a layer from which the daemon has the context to the location of requirements.txt in the docker image.

More about it in [dockerfile-best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Answer (score -3):

you can change your directory as follow

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

instead of:

```
cd path
```

also try to use:

```
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

instead of:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then execute your code:

```
!pip install .
```

or

```
!pip install -e .
```

in conclusion try this:

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
!pip install .
```